# Elasticsearch: choose TOP N documents and apply query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm sorry I'm not good at English, please understand it.

Let's assume I have such data:

```
title    category    price
book1      study     10
book2      cook      20
book3      study     30
book4      study     40
book5      art       50
```

I can do "search books in 'study' category and sort them by price-descending order". Result would be:

```
book4 - book3 - book1
```

However, I couldn't find a way to do
"search books in 'study' category AMONG the books of TOP 40% in price".
(I wish 'TOP 40% in price' is correct expression)
In this case, result should be "book4" only, because "category search" would be performed for only book5 and book4.

At first, I thought I could do it by

1. sort all documents by price
2. select TOP 40%
3. post another query for category search among them

But now, I still have no idea how I can post a query among "part of documents", not all documents. After 2, I'd have a list of documents in TOP 40%. But how can I make a query which is applied to just them?

I realized that I don't know even "search TOP n%" in elasticsearch. Is there a way that is better than "sort all and select first n%"?

Any advice would be appreciated.
And this is my first question in stackoverflow. If my question is violating any rule of here, please tell me so that I can know it and apology.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your data is [normally distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), or some other statistical distribution from which you can make sense of the data, you can probably do this in two queries.

You can take a look at the data in histogram form by doing:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
    "stats": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "price",
        "interval": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I usually take this data into a spreadsheet to chart it and do other statistical analysis on it. "interval" above will need to be some reasonable value, 100 might not be the right fit.

The is just to decide how to code the intermediate step. Provided the data is normally distributed you can then get the statistical information about the collection using this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "facets": {
    "stats": {
      "statistical": {
        "field": "price"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above gives you an output that looks like this:

```
count: 819517
total: 24249527030
min: 32
max: 53352
mean: 29590.023184387876
sum_of_squares: 875494716806082
variance: 192736269.99554798
std_deviation: 13882.94889407679
```

(the above is not based on your data sample, but just sample of available data I have to demonstrate statistical facet usage.)

So now that you know all of that, you can start applying your knowledge of statistics to the problem at hand. That is, find the Z score at the 60th percentile and find the location of the representative data point based on that.

How your final query looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "talent_profile": {
        "gte": 40,
        "lte": 50
      }
    }
  }
```

the lte is going to be from the "max" from the stats facet and the gte is going to be from your intermediate analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. My data is not guaranteed to be normally distributed or to follow any other statistical meaningful distribution. But now I know it's impossible to get a result using one query, I'm going to try to apply your answer to my situation. :) In addition, today I realize I don't need "sort all" process. I could get N'th document of sorted using "size:1" and "from:N" query option. Then I could use the field of that document as threshold. (unless I misunderstand elasticsearch)

Comment: Yeah, you got it right. It's the RDBMS equivalent of limit and offset.

Comment: Late to the party but: this could be done in the future with Fieldcollapsing/grouping. Sadly, it hasn't landed yet in Elasticsearch, see one of the more popular issues: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256